# How can pathlib read_text() method display German Umlaute correctly on Windows 10 Enterprise?

Tags: python, windows, character-encoding, text-files, pathlib

I have problems reading a text file `textFile1` with the following content:

> Das erste Mal war noch in der Audition-Phase bei einem Screentest.
> Sie haben mir das alte Kostüm von einem meiner Vorgänger, Val Kilmer, gegeben.
> Es war verrückt.
> Ich weiss noch genau, wie ich es mir angezogen habe und dachte, Batman zu spielen wird hier drinnen unmöglich sein für mich, völlig ausgeschlossen!

```
from pathlip import Path
p = Path('textFile1')
p.read_text()
```

The language is German and some of the characters are not displayed correctly:

> 'Das erste Mal war noch in der Audition-Phase bei einem Screentest.\nSie haben mir das alte Kost**Ã¼**m von einem meiner Vorg**Ã¤**nger, Val Kilmer, gegeben.\nEs war verr**Ã¼**ckt.\nIch weiss noch genau, wie ich es mir angezogen habe und dachte, Batman zu spielen wird hier drinnen unmÃ¶glich sein f**Ã¼**r mich, v**Ã¶**llig ausgeschlossen!\n'

I came across this problem on another occasion when I tried to import a table into postgreSQL. A workaround was to enter the following from the command line:

```
chcp 1252
psql -U postgres
SET client_encoding='WIN1252'
\i Path/to/your/.sqlFile
```

I am working on a Windows machine (Windows 10 Enterprise). Is there a way to solve the problem without changing the client_encoding every time I read text files from the command line? I have done quit a lot of research on this topic but I couldn't find a way to change the settings permanently. It seems to be a "Windows problem", because on my Mac all the characters are displayed correctly.

Comment: Did you try `p.read_text(encoding='UTF-8' )` ?

Comment: Thanks, that works. Seems to be a Windwos problem...

Comment: default encoding is platform dependent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p.read_text(encoding='UTF-8' )